# To change colour in Shell which is implemented in C

Tags: c

I got this else if statement in my shell that I am currently working on. When i write color in my shell it out puts the printf statement which says "to change to black background and red font colour type :color 0r". However the other bit doesn't work. So if I type 0r to change the colour it doesn't do anything. Can someone help me please.

Thank You

```
else if (strcmp(argv[0], "color")== 0) {
    printf("to change to black background and red font colour type :color 0r ");  

      if ((strcmp(argv[0], "color 0r")== 0)){

      printf("\e[40m\e[0;31m");
      }


  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first argument be in `argv[1]`? Also, the `\e` sequence is a GCC extension. And remember that `stdout` is line-buffered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line arguments are split on spaces. To do what you want, you need to compare the *next* argument for `0r` if the first one is `color`. You need to check `argc` first -- there may not be another argument after `color`.

Usually `argv[0]` contains the name of your executable. You may want to start checking at `argv[1]`.